# Angular2 Opens a new window to jump to an external URL

Tags: javascript, angular

As the title, help people answer, in angular2 how in a component of the TypeScript file to open a new window Jump to an external Web site. A request to the success of the back-end interface will return to the absolute path of a document url, but direct use winow.open () method to open the absolute path can not be achieved.

```
this.http.get(hostUrl+'exportArticle?type=add')
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(success=> {
  if(success.status==1){
    //this.fileUrl=success.data;
    //window.open(this.fileUrl);
    window.open('http://down.360safe.com/360safe_cq.exe');
  }else{
    alert(success.msg);
  }
},
err=>{console.log(err)}
)
```